# Create labels automatically from sent emails in Gmail, same for recipient's end

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Is there a way to automatically create a label in Gmail once you send it, which could also create the label on the receiving side of the email?

I want to have labels automatically generated on both my end and the recipient's. Is that possible?

Or maybe create a unique ID to keep track of that email sent history?

Answer (score 2):

On your end: Gmail does not support filtering or automatic actions on messages you send. You must label the conversation manually after you send the email.

On the other end: You want to "activate the label on the receiving side of the email"? You want control over someone else's mailbox? I don't think so.

Comment: Well the only reason I want to have control over the labels is to keep certain activities or conversations history together and not separate. This is basically a design idea I had for keeping track of CRM activities.

Comment: @Novazero labels are indeed a way to group messages, but I don't see how auto setting them up on sent messages could help you to achieve this.

Comment: This did not answer the person's question, they were asking for an alternative to creating folders for example in windows, which allows users to send organized information!